# RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync Argument exception

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I use the following code to render an `UIElement`.

```
var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await bitmap.RenderAsync(elementToRender); //this line throws the exception

var pixelBuffer = await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

var wb = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
wb = await wb.FromPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight);

var stream = await wb.GetStream();
```

this is my xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="elementToRender" Background="White" Width="400" Height="400">
    <Ellipse Fill="Black" />
</Grid>
```

I call this method after the page is loaded, but if I try to use this code i get an exception, this is the stacktrace:

```
  System.ArgumentException 
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Given that (as far as I know) WritableBitmap doesn't have a FromPixelBuffer method (plus it is returning a Task and a framework method would typically end in "Async") - I will assume that this is your own extension method? Could you paste the code to this method?

Comment: the problem is this line "await bitmap.RenderAsync(elementToRender);", i get the exception there

Comment: In that case... is this similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642908/rendertargetbitmap-renderasync-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range

Comment: as i have written i call the method after the event loaded is raised from the page

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue, please provide how you get the  `elementToRender` object.

Comment: What is elementToRender?

Comment: Element to render is the grid, anyway i have solved the issue (and I have forgot to close the question) the problem was that the xaml element that contains the "elementToRender" has it's own visibility set to Collapsed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the xaml element that contains the "elementToRender" has it's own visibility set to Collapsed